# DVI (via Thunderbolt) display doesn't sleep reliably

Tags: mac-mini, power-management

My new Mac Mini (late 2018) has 3 monitors connected - one via HDMI and two Thunderbolt-to-DVI. The two DVI monitors are both [HP 2011x](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c02643130), and I had them previously connected to a now-retired Mac Pro, where I was using DisplayPort to DVI instead.

The monitors work fine, but both HP monitors have intermittent problems when going into power-saving mode. Sometimes they're fine: when it's time for the monitors to go to sleep, I get a message on-screen saying "Monitor going to sleep", the power LED turns from blue to amber, and the monitor stays like that until it's woken by me.

However, more often than not I get the same "Monitor going to sleep", the LED goes from blue to amber - and then back to blue a second later. The "Monitor going to sleep" message then appears, and the process repeats ad infinitum. Sometimes one of the two monitors goes to sleep successfully, whilst it's companion gets stuck in the loop. The HDMI-connected monitor - a ViewSonic VX2452 - goes to sleep normally.

I've tried playing around with various power-saving settings, all to no avail. It's not a huge issue, but it's quite annoying - considering it worked fine on the Mac Pro via DisplayPort.

EDIT: Here's the `system_profiler` information:

```
% system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType
Graphics/Displays:

    Intel UHD Graphics 630:

      Chipset Model: Intel UHD Graphics 630
      Type: GPU
      Bus: Built-In
      VRAM (Dynamic, Max): 1536 MB
      Vendor: Intel
      Device ID: 0x3e9b
      Revision ID: 0x0000
      Metal: Supported, feature set macOS GPUFamily2 v1
      Displays:
        HP 2011:
          Resolution: 1600 x 900
          UI Looks like: 1600 x 900 @ 60 Hz
          Framebuffer Depth: 30-Bit Color (ARGB2101010)
          Display Serial Number: xxxx  
          Main Display: Yes
          Mirror: Off
          Online: Yes
          Rotation: Supported
          Automatically Adjust Brightness: No
          Connection Type: DVI or HDMI
          Adapter Firmware Version: 0.00
        HP 2011:
          Resolution: 1600 x 900
          UI Looks like: 1600 x 900 @ 60 Hz
          Framebuffer Depth: 30-Bit Color (ARGB2101010)
          Display Serial Number: xxxx 
          Mirror: Off
          Online: Yes
          Rotation: Supported
          Automatically Adjust Brightness: No
          Connection Type: DVI or HDMI
          Adapter Firmware Version: 0.00
        VX2452 Series:
          Resolution: 1920 x 1080 (1080p FHD - Full High Definition)
          UI Looks like: 1920 x 1080 @ 60 Hz
          Framebuffer Depth: 30-Bit Color (ARGB2101010)
          Display Serial Number: xxxx
          Mirror: Off
          Online: Yes
          Rotation: Supported
          Adapter Type: DVI or HDMI
          Automatically Adjust Brightness: No
          Adapter Firmware Version: 2.19
```

Comment: Monitors come out of sleep because it has detected a signal.  Since you’re converting from DisplayPort to DVI make sure you’re using an active adapter\cable.  What adapter are you using?

Comment: I'm *not* converting from DisplayPort any more - I was on the Mac Pro (where sleep worked fine), but on this Mac Mini I'm going straight from Thunderbolt->DVI

Comment: Thunderbolt is DisplayPort.  See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275037/119271

Comment: OK, but I'm not explicitly using DisplayPort (as I was on the Mac Pro) - I'm plugging straight from Thunderbolt 3 to DVI. It's an all-in-one cable, Thunderbolt/USB-C on one end, DVI on the other: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07HFDDGQ2/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Issue the command `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType`.  Tell me what it says for the very last line

Comment: @Allan: Added above; I've given the entire output just in case it's useful

Comment: It’s supposed to say “Thunderbolt/DisplayPort” on the HP monItors and not “DVI or HDMI” because the cable that you linked to is unidirectional; it doesn’t (at least not supposed to) communicate back to the computer. I would try a different cable.

Comment: Try this.  https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-DisplayPort-USB-C-Supporting/dp/B01J6DT070  it specifically says Thunderbolt to DisplayPort

Comment: I'm confused - the HP 2011x doesn't have a DisplayPort connector, only DVI and VGA (https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c02643130). Wouldn't that mean that I'd need to have a DisplayPort->DVI connector for each monitor too?

Comment: On your Mac, the Thunderbolt 3 ports, which use the USB-C connector output a DisplayPort signal.  So, to connect to DVI or VGA you need a Thunderbolt Type C to DVI cable/adapter; and yes, you need one for each monitor.

Comment: I already have Thunderbolt->DVI cables - that's what I'm using just now, but as you've said the issue may be that they're "unidirectional" (which I didn't realise was a "thing" with DVI). It's not enough of an issue to cause me to repurchase different cables in the uncertain hope that it'll fix the problem, and I certain don't want to go down the Thunderbolt->DisplayPort-to-DVI adapter->DVI kludge. Perhaps it's time to write it off as "just one of those things" ...

Comment: If the cables are cheap and you're going to use these for a long time, I would look at new ones.  When getting a new monitor - go DisplayPort all the way (HDMI is too flaky) and you'll get a consistent, reliable connection.  After spending a few years fighting with HDMI, I researched things and found DP to to be the best.